# How to list directory contents recursively?

Tags: scripts

I need help with a script that displays the subdirectory structure of the current directory, along with the names of files in these subdirectories.

I've tried commands `tree`, `ls`, and `grep` but it is hard to find the exact command(s) I need.

Comment: `ls -R` isn't that what you want?

Comment: What are you trying to do? To “display the subdirectories structure”, that would be `tree`. How is `tree` not what you want? Explain more clearly, perhaps with an example of the output you want.

Comment: Yes i want sctruture so probably it will be Tree . Sorry for missunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the `tree` package :

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

Command :

```
 $ tree -l
```

The "l" option:

```
  -l     Follows  symbolic links if they point to directories, as if they
              were directories. Symbolic links that will result  in  recursion
              are avoided when detected.
```

Output :

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1.png
│   └── Untitled Document
├── 10271474_10154132320890137_6530350599362308925_n.jpg
└── f
    ├── a.html
    ├── b.html
    └── d.css

2 directories, 6 files
```

I have 2 directories :

```
1 and f and a jpg file in ~/Desktop  and list file in 1 and f
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the directory structure (i.e. just directories): `find . -type d`

To display everything mixed together: `find .`

To display everything with more details so you can figure out what is file and what a directory: `find . -ls`